# How to make sure the accessed index in a vector exists?

Tags: c++, vector, sfml, assert

I have a vector of text labels `std::vector<sf::Text> texts_`. I can create texts and push them into the vector like this:

```
texts_.push_back(utils::createText(x, y, "SomeString1"));
texts_.push_back(utils::createText(x, y, "SomeString2"));
// etc.
```

and then easily draw them like this:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < texts_.size(); ++i) {
  renderTarget.draw(texts_.at(i));
}
```

I occasionally want to update the texts' strings. What I currently do is:

```
texts_.at(0).setString("SomeUniqueString1");
texts_.at(1).setString("SomeUniqueString2");
texts_.at(2).setString("SomeUniqueString3");
// ...
```

All of the above works just fine. **Now to the problem:**

When updating the strings, what if I accidentally try to access an index of for example 10 even though there are only for example 5 texts in the vector?

If I do that the program will obviously crash. I could check each time if the index is less than the vector's size but that's kind of overkill (I'd have to add a lot more checks to the code...)? How can I without much effort make sure that the text at that index exists in the vector?

Comment: _"If I do that the program will obviously crash."_ No, not obviously. Because you are using `v.at(0)` it will throw an exception, which you can catch and handle appropriately. If you were using `v[0]` it might crash (or do something worse) but `vector::at()` does range checking.

Comment: If you don't know whether an index in your vector is valid at any point in the program it'll be because your vector has changed while you held on to an reference (the index). This would represent a design flaw - because it's not logically correct to depend on a reference to data that may no longer be there. Perhaps it's time to reconsider the design? Or is it possible that you're being paranoid? It might help to analyse the execution paths. Any path that mutates data should not hold on to references.

Comment: I agree with @RichardHodges, if you try to access an index of 10 even though there are only for example 5 elements in the vector, it is indicative of a design flaw; you should either redesign your code to ensure there are always at least 10 elements in the vector, or, better yet, don't hardcode your index values. You may even want to look at a different container type (instead of vector), if it doesn't meet your requirements.

Answer (score 4):

If the amount of boilerplate you'd need to write bothers you, just write it once in a function.

```
template<class T, typename ValueType>
void SafeSetValue(T & container, size_t index, const ValueType & value)
{
    if (index < container.size())
        container[index] = value;
}

SafeSetValue(texts_, 0, "SomeUniqueString1");
```

You can change the function to do something different in the case of an out-of-bounds index.

Comment: I don't like this: vector::at already provides range checking, signed/unsigned compare, copy by value (eliminating optimizations provided by the container), assumption the operator [] exists.

Comment: @DieterLücking since the bounds checking of `at` is redundant in this function I thought it would be better to use `operator[]`. You can use whatever you wish in your own code. It didn't occur to me immediately that I should pass the string by reference, I thought of making an edit later but decided not to. I've changed my mind, give me a second and let me know what you think of the changes.

Comment: @RichardHodges, maybe so. I try to assume a question has a good reason behind it, because I'm constantly surprised by my failures of imagination.

Comment: @MarkRansom I understand, but in this case I can assure you that the program is logically incorrect :-)

Answer (score 0):

> If I do that the program will obviously crash. I could check each time if the index is less than the vector's size but that's kind of overkill (I'd have to add a lot more checks to the code...)? How can I without much effort make sure that the text at that index exists in the vector?

If you're accessing the elements using `std::vector<>::at()`, the check is being performed. If the index is out of range, then an exception will be thrown. Other member functions (notably `operator[]`) are *not* checked.